# python else part in if runs many times , how to solve

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement

here is my code for showing search record and showing inform usr if found nothing.
Problem: else part runs as many times as outer loop.

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'},
           {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'},
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]    
search = input("type your search: ")
            print(search)
            for person in entries:
                # print(person)
                if person["Last Name"] == search:
                    print("Here are the records found for your search")
                    for e in person:
                        print(e, ":", person[e])
                else:
                    print("There is no record found as you search Keyword")
```

Comment: Check out my code.

Comment: Your inner for loop should be for key in person.keys(): print(key, " : ",person [key])

Comment: why not use pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if the `Last Name` that the user enters is present in the `dictionaries`. If yes, then loop through them and `print` the respective records. Else, display `no records found`. Here is how you do it:

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'},
           {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'},
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]
search = input("type your search: ")
print(search)
if search in [person['Last Name'] for person in entries]:
    for person in entries:
        if person["Last Name"] == search:
            print("Here are the records found for your search")
            for e in person:
                print(e, ":", person[e])
else:
    print("There is no record found as you search Keyword")
```

Output:

```
type your search: >? Khan
Khan
Here are the records found for your search
First Name : Sher
Last Name : Khan
Age : 22
Telephone : 2989484
Here are the records found for your search
First Name : Ali
Last Name : Khan
Age : 22
Telephone : 398439
Here are the records found for your search
First Name : Talha
Last Name : Khan
Age : 22
Telephone : 3343434
```

```
type your search: >? Jones
Jones
There is no record found as you search Keyword
```

Comment: Add a `Jones` record at the end of data and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

thats because each iteration you are checking only 1 person, and if you didn't find what you looked for, you are printing that it does not exist.
this is actually an undesired behavior.

a better solution would be to simply look in the set of values you need:

```
...
search = input("type your search: ")
founds = [entry for entry in entries if entry["Last Name"] == search)]  ## filtering only records that match what we need using list comprehension
if founds:
    for found in founds:
        * print info  *
else:
    print("There is no record found as you search Keyword")
```

Comment: I would use this for other implementation , Thanks

Comment: awesome!
please mark it as 'accepted' so other can view it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this (Use a boolean Found variable)

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'},
           {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'},
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'},
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]    
search = input("type your search: ")
found = False
print(search)
for person in entries:
  if person["Last Name"] == search:
    found = True
    print("Here are the records found for your search")
    for e in person:
      print(e, ":", person[e])

if not found:
  print("There is no record found as you search Keyword")
```

Comment: Side note. If you want to use python it's MUCH better if you adopt the standard formatting of using 4 spaces for indenting, not 2. It's just a convention but will make working with others (and tools) much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way of doing it but this would work I think

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': 
'2989484'},
       {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'},
       {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': 
'3343434'}]
inEntries = False    
search = input("type your search: ")
        print(search)
        for person in entries:
            # print(person)
            if person["Last Name"] == search:
                inEntries = True
                print("Here are the records found for your search")
                for e in person:
                    print(e, ":", person[e])
         if not inEntries:  
             print("There is no record found as you search Keyword")
```